# Fiddler HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, authorization, fiddler

I have local Web API project which is NOT running through local IIS. To run the project I use F5 in Visual Studio 2013.

Using Fiddler, I keep getting:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

#   Result  Protocol    Host    URL Body    Caching Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom  88  401 HTTP    localhost:52787 /api/values 6,180   private text/html; charset=utf-8    fiddler:10724
```

I know I am supposed to get 200 but I am not. Where should I check what I am doing wrong?

Here is a screenshot from a browser. I am getting this when I go back to Fiddler to see the results, I just type `http://localhost:52787/api/helloapi` into URL (in a browser) and press enter:

[image]

And here is what I get when I go through Fiddler manually composing GET:

[image]

I have the option Automatically Authenticate checked.

Comment: Your API either requires authentication or the operation is coded such that it returns a httpwebresponse of 404. You haven't provided enough info for an answer.

Comment: yes I have this in front of api controller and I added Users = my name in there [Authorize(Users="...my user name...")] It still does not work. What I don't know is this ... where does it look for those users? Where can I check. I have no other authentication configured anywhere.

Comment: Those should be local computer users. Does it work from a browser instead of fiddler?

Comment: Yes it does work from a browser but I want it to work in Fiddler. Okay the web.api project is a default I have not modified anything in it and I put this in an api controller User.Identity.IsAuthenticated.ToString() which gives me back false. So I crated asp.net project and did the same thing it gives me back true. ?????

Comment: Do it from the browser again but also run fiddler and inspect the traffic. Maybe you need to set an Authorization header in your request.

Answer (score 9):

When you say "using Fiddler", what *exactly* do you mean?

If you are manually composing the request using Fiddler's **Composer**, either add an `Authorization` header yourself, or click the Composer's **Options** tab and check the `Automatically Authenticate` box.

Comment: Updated my original question. Yes I am using Fiddler's Composer. I have the option Automatically Authenticate checked but still getting the same result.

Comment: Use Fiddler' "Copy Headers" feature to copy the HTTP response headers on the 401 response to update your question. And to be clear, you see *exactly* one HTTP/401, not two, when you click Execute?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same Problem. In my case it was caused by a deny clause in the web.config that forced all users to be authenticated. This works well in a browser because this handles the authentication behind the scenes and sends an appropriate authorization Cookie. In Fiddler this handshake does not take place and hence the 401. In the development environment add this to your web.config and it should work.

```
<system.web>
       <authorization> 
           <allow users="?" /> 
      </authorization>  
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post but if someone is still looking for an answer (like me) and the above answers did not resolve the problem then try this solution -

The above answers didn't work in my dev env which consists of VS 2017 and VSTS as I already had the `<authorization>` element set correctly in my web.config file. After a few hit and trials I figured that the source of the problem was somewhere else.

I needed to make the following change to "applicationhost.config" file which can be usually found under the path "`C:\Users\xxx\Source\Repos\yyy\yyy\.vs\config`" -

Locate the `<anonymousAuthentication>` element and make sure the "enabled" attribute is set to "true"  as under:

```
       <system.webServer>
            <security>
                <authentication>
                    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
                    <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
                </authentication>
            </security>
        </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you have an Authorize attribute on your ValuesController
[Authorize]
public class ValuesController : ApiController

Just remove [Authorize] attribute on ValuesController